# Will Apple Review Team Approve Cocoa App Which Has Added Apple Script To Open System Preferences?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, mac-app-store, entitlements

Hey folks I have been developing cocoa app which has functionality to automate one task which does the following - :

- 1 - open system preferences
- 2 - open network preferences
- 3 - click button "Advanced.."
- 4 - select "Proxy" tab
- 5 - select check box "Automatic Proxy Configuration"
- 6 - fills URL of proxy configuration file path
- 7 - click button "OK"
- 8 - click button "Apply"

All above steps are happing automatically on button action.
I know that in order to make this work I need to add a temporary exception of apple event in entitlements file.
I have got good reference thanks to [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/) I need to know if someone tried to achieve the same.

Comment: We tried to achieve something similar and it was not approved. Script System Preferences is not appropriate for sandbox. There might be other API to configure proxy.

Comment: so does that mean we can not submit app which has added Apple Script to automate task even if we have user's permission.